# Is there a way to change a selector's properties and values with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is there a way to entirely change css properties and their values for a selector onclick? Maybe that isn't necessary. Right now I'm using jquerymobile and I overrode the default listview styles simply with an li selector and !important after values. I have an image that I'm using as a button that is contained within each listview. When it's clicked, I want to be able to append a class to to the listview in order to replace the styles I'm already using to override the default with new styling.

Comment: Something like `.addClass()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for, just replace .examplebutton with the class on your button, example1 is the class you are replacing and example2 is the new class name.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.examplebutton').click(function() {
$('.example1').removeClass('example1').addClass('example2');            
}); // end click
}); // end ready
</script>
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

`.css()` have 3 constructor

```
var appliedStyles = $(selector).css();
$(selector).css("display", "block");
$(selector).css({"display":"block", "margin":"20px", "padding":"5px"});
```

To add new class to the selector

```
$(selector).addClass(className);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use .addClass to add a class with your appropriate styling or, You can use jquery's .css().

http://api.jquery.com/css/